# Requests JSON body for inbound voice calls

Tags: vonage

I can't find any strict information about two requests with are made by Nexmo to "*answer*" end "*event*" services. I'm confused.

When I make a call to my virtual number first is my "*answer*" URL is called. Question is how JSON body of that request looks like? Can you provide me some example of that request to "*answer*" URL?

Then after welcome speach user make a choise and "event" service is called. As I understand JSON body for that POST request looks like that:

```
{
    "dtmf": "2",
    "timed_out": false,
    "uuid": "cwa3126675f721esueedc762c9ft94b7",
    "conversation_uuid": "CON-w4e9ae1-28ka-1234-ic63-65d022433343",
    "timestamp": "2018-01-27T17:59:39.963Z"
}
```

Am I right?

Best regards,

Radek

Answer (score 2):

The webhook to your answer event contains 4 values:

`to`:   The endpoint being called.
`from`:     The endpoint you are calling from.
`conversation_uuid`:    The unique ID for this Conversation.
`uuid`:     The unique ID for this Call.

By default this request is a GET and those will be query params, you can change the method to POST if you need it in that format and you will get JSON like this:

```
{
    "from": "447700900001",
    "to": "447700900002",
    "uuid": "CON-9faebf2c-6609-40e2-adaa-95444b6ca352",
    "conversation_uuid": "CON-9faebf2c-6609-40e2-adaa-95444b6ca352"
}
```

The 'Call Progress Events' reference is here, generally there are 2/3 different categories of events:
Call progess which is things like when the call is `started` `answered` & `completed` and then 2 other events which are in response to an `input` action or a `record` action.

https://developer.nexmo.com/api/voice#webhook

I must apologize it's currently not as easy as it should be to find this in our docs, but we've just started a rewrite of these pages and hopefully it will be much clearer soon.